# gulp-typescript compiler doesn't compile my files

Tags: windows, typescript, gulp

I'm trying to bring a typescript app out of an ASP.NET MVC environment into a seperate app to seperate frontend and backend needs.

The typescript remains unchanged and I tried to compile the typescript with `gulp` but the code doesn't seem to compile. I followed [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-a-typescript-workflow-with-gulp) blogpost by Dan Wahlin. But the typescript doesn't seem to compile. I'm on a Windows 8.1 laptop with Visual Studio 2015 Premium installed.

The directory structure of my project is as follows:

```
/

-- App/
---- Controllers/
------ xxController.ts

-- Scripts/
---- typings/
------ xxlibrary/
-------- library.d.ts
---- tsd.d.ts
```

The files I have are the following:

Gulpfile.config.js:

```
'use strict';
var GulpConfig = (function () {
function gulpConfig() {

    this.source = '/App';

    this.tsOutputPath = '/Scripts';
    this.allJavaScript = ['/Scripts/**/*.js'];
    this.allTypeScript = this.source + '/**/*.ts';

    this.typings = '/Scripts/typings';
    this.libraryTypeScriptDefinitions = this.typings + '/**/*.ts';
}
return gulpConfig;
})();
module.exports = GulpConfig;
```

Please note that when I use the './' notation as shown in Dan Wahlin's config gulp gives me an exception:

```
    [11:08:11] Using gulpfile D:\Files\Work\Source\ImageManagement\Imagemanagement.App\Gulpfile.js
    [11:08:11] Starting 'ts-lint'...
    [11:08:11] Starting 'compile-ts'...
    stream.js:94
    throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
    ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    debug = require('gulp-debug'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject'),
    tsc = require('gulp-typescript'),
    tslint = require('gulp-tslint'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    del = require('del'),
    Config = require('./gulpfile.config'),
    tsProject = tsc.createProject('tsconfig.json'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    superstatic = require('superstatic');

var config = new Config();

/**
 * Compile TypeScript and include references to library and app .d.ts files.
 */
gulp.task('compile-ts', function () {
    var sourceTsFiles = [config.allTypeScript,                //path to typescript files
                         config.libraryTypeScriptDefinitions]; //reference to library .d.ts files


    var tsResult = gulp.src(sourceTsFiles)
                       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                       .pipe(tsc(tsProject));

    tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest(config.tsOutputPath));
    return tsResult.js
                    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tsOutputPath));
});
```

When I run this gulpfile.js there is no error thrown but there is no output in the `Scripts` as I expect.

```
    [11:15:08] Using gulpfile D:\Files\Work\Source\ImageManagement\Imagemanagement.App\Gulpfile.js
    [11:15:08] Starting 'compile-ts'...
    [11:15:08] Finished 'compile-ts' after 6.84 ms
    Process terminated with code 0.
```

Comment: Could you just run the compile-ts task (`gulp compile-ts`) and whittle your question down to exclude all the other tasks? That way we can isolate the problem. Btw, try doing this: 1. Use [`gulp-debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) to ensure you are getting the files in `gulp.src(sourceTsFiles)`. 2. Try doing: `return gulp.src(sourceTsFiles).pipe(sourcemaps.init()).pipe(ts(tsProject)).pipe(sourcemaps.write("./")).pipe(gulp.dest(config.tsOutputPath));` in `compile-ts` instead.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and I hope I did it right: 1. added .pipe(debug(sourceTsFiles)) to the line of code and that outputs `[16:52:05] gulp-debug: 0 items` 

I've tried refactoring to this but it didn't improve: 
`        return gulp.src(sourceTsFiles)
            .pipe(debug(sourceTsFiles))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(tsc(tsProject))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tsOutputPath));`

Comment: Ok, forget about the second part I mentioned then. If you do: `gulp.src(sourceTsFiles).pipe(debug())` the `0 items` means that `gulp.src(sourceTsFiles)` isn't finding any files. Make sure the paths being passed into that are correct. Right now it looks like it's looking in `/App/**/*.ts`

Comment: And that is where it should look since that is the location where my .ts code resides. As you can see in my directory structure. The `/App/**/*.ts` is a relative path, right?

Comment: I think you have to use dot notation for all your paths—`./App/**/*.ts`. See what debug spits out after doing that. If it shows all the correct files then the problem lies after the `.src(sourceTsFiles)` line.

Comment: If I try that then the gulp task gives me an error shown in the question

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the issue.
When I change this:

```
'use strict';
var GulpConfig = (function () {
function gulpConfig() {
[...]
    this.allTypeScript = this.source + '/**/*.ts';
[...]
    this.libraryTypeScriptDefinitions = this.typings + '/**/*.ts';
}
return gulpConfig;
})();
module.exports = GulpConfig;
```

To

```
'use strict';
var GulpConfig = (function () {
function gulpConfig() {
[...]
    this.allTypeScript = './App/**/*.ts';
[...]
    this.libraryTypeScriptDefinitions = './Scripts/typings/**/*.ts';
}
return gulpConfig;
})();
module.exports = GulpConfig;
```

It works just fine. Not sure why though.